# How to use the latest set of Fluent UI icons for SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, icons, fluent-ui

I am using the code from here

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/icon

which is

```
import { FontIcon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';

<FontIcon iconName="Forward" />
```

I believe these use `https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/icons/fabric-icons-a13498cf.woff`

but sometimes icons do not render. How do I ensure I am referencing the latest set?

Also if there is ever updates to the icon set, will this code just be able to access the new icons on its own or do I need to do something manual like re-compile the sppkg and upload it again to the app catalogue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';
```

and the you can get the icons like

```
<Icon iconName='Move' />
```

Comment: Why do this and not FontIcon though?

Comment: Also if new icons are released, does it pick it up automatically or do I need to manually do anything?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation,

1. When we want to use **basic icon** or **Icon with custom color** or **Icon using custom svg**, we need to use FontIcon component.
2. When we want to use **Icon using image sheet**, we need to use ImageIcon component.
3. When we want to **Icon using svg factory**, we need to use Icon component.

You can choose different components according to your needs.

Comment: It seems using `Icon` made some broken icons render. But going forward, how does updates to icons work? If more are released, how can I ensure using `Icon` will be able to pick it up? Or is it automatically referencing the latest one and there is no need to re-compile and deploy?

Comment: Could you share the link to the documentation for the FontIcon and ImageIcon components?